# Custom Experience Editor Buttons - no fields appear

Tags: experience-editor

I have a rendering based on a data source. One of the fields on the data source is a DropLink. I added a Custom Experience Editor Button to the rendering to edit the DropLink. The field I want to edit is called Theme:

[image]

My custom button appears in the experience editor:[image]

But when I click on it, the popup has no fields available to edit:[image]

Comment: can you verify if you switch content editor to master db from core db?

Comment: Yes. Definitely on Master.

Comment: @EthanSchofer, for me it seems that Sitecore is returning the field but cannot render it. If no fields were found, you would not even have the Section `Data`. Can you please first check in the logs if there are any errors. Moreover, check if there are any whitespaces in the `Fields` from core database. Another thing, does the user has admin access since it may be that the item is locked or has no write access to it

Comment: @EthanSchofer Also make sure "Theme" is the actual item name of the field.  And it needs to be the field that the rendering is pulling in (either Context Item, Datasource, or via query).

Comment: @EthanSchofer can you post a screenshot of the field item under the template including the field type if possible?

Comment: @DylanYoung Can you add this as an answer so I can mark as accepted?

Comment: @EthanSchofer I've added that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When specifying fields for the `Field Editor Button` type button, make sure the Fields you specify are using the **Item Name** instead of the Display Name.

Additionally, you must make sure that field that you are specifying in the `Fields` field, maps directly to the same field in the data that's being displayed by your rendering.

I covered this and other topics related to creating `Field Editor Buttons` in Sitecore in my video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D6jqqaBMu0s&t=25s

Comment: I marked this as the answer because its how I found the answer, but its not a direct explanation of the problem. Basically, my Model was made up of child models and the editor button on the parent rendering but trying to access a field in the child model. So the field was not technically on the rendering. I solved this by using an edit frame.

Comment: I actually found this happens in another scenario tonight.  Basically if you've specified fields that don't exist either in the datasource (because you haven't specified a datasource yet, or it's from an item that isn't the current context item, you would get this issue.